# How to define a multidimensional array in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I am working on GUI programming for Python using Tkinter.
I want to define a multidimensional array.I've tried the following code but it is showing an error.

```
subMenu =[sub1[],sub2[],sub3[],sub4[],sub5[]]

sub1 = ["New File","Save File","Edit File","Open File","Exit"]
sub2 = ["Undo","Redo","Cut","Copy","Paste"]
sub3 = ["Run","Check Module","Debug","compile","Close"]
sub4 = ["Undo","Redo","Cut","Copy","Paste"]
sub5 = ["Undo","Redo","Cut","Copy","Paste"]
```

How can I define a multidimensional-array in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error with assigning a list inside a list. 
It should be

```
sub1 = ["New File", "Save File", "Edit File", "Open File", "Exit"]
sub2 = ["Undo", "Redo", "Cut", "Copy", "Paste"]
sub3 = ["Run", "Check Module", "Debug", "compile", "Close"]
sub4 = ["Undo", "Redo", "Cut", "Copy", "Paste"]
sub5 = ["Undo", "Redo", "Cut", "Copy", "Paste"]

# correct way of assigning 
subMenu = [sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5]
```

When you try to pretty print subMenu, it should be like this:
[image]

Comment: Thank You.Can You please tell me how to access that values also

Comment: Hi Varun, you can access them using their index. Say you want to access the "New File" element. It is the first element of the subMenu and the first element also in that element, so you can access it using `subMenu[0][0]`.